# Как сделать блок некликабельным

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт выпадающего блока, проблема в том, если его открыть, то он закрывается по любому клику (не важно кликните вы по открывшимся блоке или за его пределами).
Подскажите, что надо изменить в коде, что бы окно закрывалось только при клике за его пределами, но не по клике по нем.

```
function DropDown(el) {
    this.dd = el;
    this.initEvents();
}

DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents: function() {
        var obj = this;

        obj.dd.on('click', function(event) {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
    }
}
$(function() {
    var dd = new DropDown($('#wrapper-polz'));

    $(document).click(function() {
        $('.wrapper-polz').removeClass('active');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Использовал вот такой скрипт

```
$(".wrapper").click(function() {
  $('.dropdown').toggle();
});
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).closest(".dropdown2").length) {
    $('.dropdown').hide();
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял вопрос, но можно блоку добавить css свойство **pointer-events** со значением **none**

```
.block {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Подробнее тут https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: И что это даст, блок начнет закрываться по клику за его приделами, или он перестанет закрываться по клику по самому блоку?.